# Number of connections from a client to servers with proxy

Tags: http, proxy

I want to make simple HTTP proxy server.

Here, I have some problem of designing the program because of the number of connections.

When a client attempts to make connection to the 2 servers, there would be 2 connections; one from client to the server A and the other from client to the server B. It is natural; at least I think.

However, I'm confused when there is a proxy between client and server. I thought the client might make only 1 connection to the proxy, and send all of HTTP message (to server A and server B) via the connection. The first method is very natural (making 2 connections for 2 servers), but I want to double-check this before starting implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Clients might make only one connection to your proxy server (using HTTP keepalive and/or pipelining to sequentially make more than one request through the same connection), or they might make multiple connections to your proxy server (especially if they want to make more than one HTTP request in parallel). You should be prepared for both eventualities because it's up to the client what it does.

The case of two HTTP requests coming over the same connection is semantically identical to the case of the same two HTTP requests coming over separate connections.